# Adding content from one xml file to other

Tags: xml

I need to know how can i edit xml file and add more content by comparing some elements from two files.
I have one file with structure like this:

```
<table name="products">
<column name="product_id">29246</column>
<column name="category_id">418</column>
<column name="product_code">31593</column>>
<column name="product_price">61.00</column>
<column name="product_name_en">GUILTI BLACK lady 75 ml</column>
<column name="product_name_lv">GUILTI BLACK lady 75 ml</column>
<column name="product_name_ru">GUILTI BLACK lady 75 ml</column>
<column name="product_description_en">Gucci Guilty Black.....en</column>
<column name="product_description_lv">Gucci Guilty Black.....lv</column>
<column name="product_description_ru">Gucci Guilty Black.....ru</column>
</table>
```

Second file is:

```
<table name="categories">
<column name="category_id">418</column>
<column name="category_name_en">Women's Perfume</column>
<column name="category_name_lv">Sieviešu parfimērija</column>
<column name="category_name_ru">Женская парфюмерия</column>
</table>
```

And i need to check if category id(from 1 file) == category id(from 2 file)
then to first file add all this category fields from second file. How can i do that or maybe there is some good xml editor or maybe other solutions.

Comment: Do you want to achieve it programatically or manually? If you want to choose first offer, then which serverside language do you use? Php, python, c?

Comment: I want to achieve it as simple as possible that's why im asking for the best solution. I use php.